# vb.net how to add and load an html file from resource into webbrowser control

Tags: html, vb.net, resources, webbrowser-control

I have a `webbrowser` control on `form2`, and the things I'd like to do are:

1. How can I add an HTML file into resource ?
2. How can I load it from resource to `webbrowser` control when an if-condition is `true`, and make it visible in the `webbrowser`?

For example:

```
 If dttest.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
  webbrowser.navigate(resources and the html name page)
 End If
```

I've already tried the `webbrowser.navigate` but I want to load the HTML page.

Comment: So your html file is a resource?

Comment: yes i wanna put one or more file inside the program through resource and load it in the webbrowser control, when the if is true.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work's for me and is tried and tested... I left the `If` condition out as it's not pertinent of what you are trying to accomplish. Also no need to call `Navigate` as when you set the `Uri` it should load the document.

```
  Dim filename As String = "test.html"
  With Me.WebBrowser1 'Change name to reflect your name
      .ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True 'I was getting script errors from site
      .Url = New Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}{1}{2}/", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/Resources/", filename))
  End With
```

**Note**

If the `Copy to Output Directory` is not set to `Copy Always` for your `html` file (file's) you need to make that change. You can right click on the `html` file and select properties. Change that property as needed.

Comment: If i understand well this part, .("file:///{0}{1}{2}/",  is like a vector for file or files right ? And if i wanna put only 1 i need to write "file:///{0} with only the 0 ?

Comment: It's normal that, when i load the file into resource of the project, it give me an text file ? I was thinking when i put the name in file name , the webbrowser decode the html inserted into that text file ?

Comment: It's possible to put web pages offline with images ? Like a full page but offline.

Comment: and now i tested the code, when the if come true, it displays on webbrowser the elements of the folder where's the exe instead of html file opened on it

Comment: i tried also, to import the htm file into the project but doesn't work i tried also with copy to output directory propriety of htm file, but it show always the elements folder, with the copy to output directory it create the bin folder with subfolder :(

Comment: @Axel mine shows up as a text file as well, but it has the `.html` extension to it. In Chrome you can save a full webpage, but some elements will not show as it's offline; tried this and most images and etc. showed just fine.

Comment: @Axel why remove the accept? I am not sure what you are doing, I can copy paste this code in a new solution, import a `html` file in the resources and this works just fine. If you are having other issue's you need to post that as it ***does not*** pertain to the question you asked.

Comment: Now i downloaded Chrome, then i follow these steps:
1)Save the page offline
2)Import it to Project through my project double click (and i selected, save as all file, after i click ok it's a txt file)
3) Changed the String of Dim filename for test and put test.html (Chrome like you said before save .html format page, i was using waterfox)
4)Run the application, search test1.
5)And on the webbrowser should i see the page i saved with Chrome ?

Comment: I have a question, it's possible to speed up the loading of the page ?

Comment: @Axel Not that I am aware of. It really shouldn't be a great deal considering it's loading from disk and ***not from the web*** which would be slower.

Comment: So, it's the same thing with a screenshot from that page ? If i load it into picturebox, will have the same loading time ?

Comment: @Axel well you are speaking different controls now, which behave differently. Loading an image to a picture box should not take very long at all and more than likely be quicker than actually loading the webpage as the web browser control has to render these elements.

Comment: mmm, with this webbrowser control it's possible to take a screenshot of a list of web pages (of course it will be a new project with a textbox for links and a webbrowser control) ?

Comment: Sorry, for ask to you this but i need a little help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800442/vb-net-how-to-take-automatic-screenshot-of-a-list-of-webpages-and-save-it-in-fol